# Why/when GetComputerName() returns 'TENTATIVE'?

Tags: windows, winapi

It appears that in some very rare cases GetComputerName() Windows API returns 'TENTATIVE' as a computer name. Based on information from our customers we suspect that this sometimes happens on laptops when they 'awaken' from a sleep. The odd thing is that this happens **after** our app is already running and able to connect to a back-end server and retrieve some information from it - i.e. the computer name is written into a log file at the time.

We are considering putting a slight delay during 'awakaning' but would like confirm that the cause is what we suspect.

We could not find anything on-line that would confirm the source of the issue.

Comment: Do you perform error checking on the call to GetComputerName?

Comment: Unfortunately, not for this call. I never thought that a simple call like that could fail.

Comment: Strange to make such a judgement rather than just implement error checking like you do for all other functions. But if it fails, then the vakue returned will be undefined, right?

Comment: You need to restart to change the name so I don't see how it would become unavailable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Maybe the assumption at the time when the code was written (many years ago) was that if such a basic call fails then there is not much that can be done. Especially because the call hasn't been failing for years on thousands of workstations.

Comment: However, I'd like to understand the meaning of 'TENTATIVE' returned in the computer name in order to remedy the issue. For example, I could keep re-trying until the name transitions to a correct one. Unfortunately, our devs and QA cannot reproduce it.

Comment: If the function fails then the name that is returned is undefined. Could just be some vakue from your program's stack.

Comment: 'TENTATIVE' name must be returned by GetComputerName(). The buffer passed to it is cleared before the call.

Comment: @bjchrome just because the function copies the string into your buffer doesn't guarantee the buffer is valid for use.  You MUST check the return value to determine that for sure. It is entirely possible that the function copies that string into the buffer first, then decides "wait a minute, that doesn't look right" and returns a failure, leaving the string in the buffer.  ALWAYS check return values of system calls!